# how to compile siphon for ios 7 and later

Tags: ios7, ios8, pjsip, i386, siphon

I tried compiling siphon ios application from ios 7 and above.
unfortunately,I am getting errors saying as

architecture not being linked to i386 and references related errors.

Here is the architecture settings under xcode build setting tab.

Can anyone provide me some solution to compile siphon successfully.
Any source code could be more helpfull for me.

Thanks in advance.